# Flutter keyboard hide not working on tab clicks

Tags: flutter, uitextfield, flutter-layout

I have one application of tabbars. one tab have textfield. It shows keyboard. I want to hide keyboard after press ob any other tab. I used below code but its still not working on other tabs.

```
return new Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        backgroundColor: blackColor,
        body: GestureDetector(
            behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
            onTap: () {
              FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
            },
            child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
              _showForm(),
            ],)
        ),
        );
```

Comment: do  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode()); when you press to switch tab

Comment: Try `Focus.clear(context);` when tab change

Answer (score 1):

you can use onTap under TabBar() like this:

```
TabBar(
        onTap: (_) => FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus(),
         tabs: [
            tab1(),
            tab2(),
)
```

this will make every tab unfocus the keyboard and move to other tab as well

Answer (score 0):

Use `FocusScope.of(context).unfocus()` when tab change.

Answer (score 0):

**when you click to change tab write below line :**

```
FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply do this

```
TabBar(
 onTap: (_) => FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus(),
 tabs: [
     // add your tabs here...
 ]
)
```